# Does 2‐indanone form a stable hydrate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, stability

Following up the question [Formation of a stable hydrate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42756).
I understand that for cyclopropanone the change in hybridization is the reason for stabilization of hydrate since it relieves the angle strain.

So, can this be further be given as a reason to state the hydrate of 2‐indanone (structure below) will be stable? I suppose upon hydration the angle will change from 120° to 109.8°, bringing the angle closer to that of a pentagon that is 108°.

[image: 1,3-dihydro-2H-inden-2-one]

I am confused if this is appropriate or if it's true. If it's wrong, please explain.

P.S. After going through the comments I understood by considering keto-enol tautomerisation that hydration might not at all be favourable.

Comment: The cyclopentane ring is not perfectly flat.

Comment: Need to remember that this compound will be more extensively enolised