Why is cyclopropane-1,1-diol more stable than cyclopentane-1,1-diol?
Cyclopropanediol has greater angular strain than cyclopentanediol so wouldn't it be more reactive and try to undergo some reaction and expand ring?

I think you're missing the point. In this "stability" of yours you need context. Likely context in this case is hydration equilibrium.

So a small ring can be more stabilized by hydration than a larger ring ? If yes, please explain.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42756/formation-of-a-stable-hydrate

Cyclopropylene glycol is more reactive than cyclopentanediol due to its three-membered ring structure, which has higher angular tension. The high tension makes cyclopropylene glycol more inclined to release stress through ring-opening reactions, thereby participating in various chemical reactions. However, the specific reaction path also depends on the reaction conditions and the reagents used. In practical applications, this high reactivity also means that cyclopropylene glycol needs to be handled and stored more carefully.
