# Does intramolecular hydrogen bonding occur with carbonic acid and geminal diols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, hydrogen-bond

Is an intramolecular hydrogen bond possible in such compounds?
What are the requisites to have intramolecular hydrogen bonding?

[image: proposed intramolecular hydrogen bond in H2CO3 and gem-diol]

Comment: In second one the two R groups are +I group as well as steric hindering hence drastically reduces stability, also there is repulsions due to lone pairs on oxygen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the intramolecular H-bonding is absent in both cases.

**Carbonic acid**

In aqueous solution of carbonic acid is a weak acid. It dissociates into its constituent ions as carbonate ions and hydrogen ions. Now, the CO3-2 ion, is stabilized by resonance and produce three equivalent resonating structures.

[image]

This makes carbonate ion more stable rather than through intra molecular H-bonding. Now, I already said that carbonic acid is weak acid means all the molecules of carbonic acid are not dissociated. The molecules of carbonic acid which remain undissociated form inter-molecualr H-bonding with each other.

[image]

One thing that carbonic acid does not exist via intra-molecular H-bonding because, there is too much ring strain.

**Gem-diols**

In gem-diols there are two -OH groups present on a single carbon. You can get detail reason that [why intra-molecular H-bonding is absent in gem-diols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/what-makes-c-o-more-stable-that-coh%E2%82%82/10739#10739).

There is a common example of gem-diol where intra molecular H-bonding is present is chloral hydrate.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! The dissociation $$\ce{H2CO3 (aq) <=> CO2 (aq) + H2O}$$ is indeed the predominant reaction, [favouring carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid#Chemical_equilibrium). That is one of the main reasons, why many carbonates readily decompose at low pHs. || Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you want to know more, please also have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Answer (score 6):

> Is this possible?

Probably not possible. An elementary explanation would be "too much ring strain."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_strain

> I'm a bit confused: What are the requisites to occur a intramolecular hydrogen bonding?

5 and 6-membered rings are more favorable. As a matter of fact, beta-ketoacids, when warmed, readily decarboxylate. Why? The intermediate to decarboxylation is stabilized through hydrogen bonding.

Note the 6-membered ring in the picture below.

[image]