# Do carboxylic acids form hydrates like aldehydes and ketones?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

Having learned that aldehydes exist in equilibrium with their hydrate form - [image: Hydrate form of Aldehyde]

Do carboxylic acids do the same in a water solvent and form a hydrate with 3 $\ce{OH}$ groups and one alkyl group?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: @Mithoron Any reason for it?

Comment: It breaks conjugation.

Comment: Such hydrates are called orthocarboxylic acids https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75588/why-are-organic-ortho-acids-unstable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho_acid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me go against the previous answers, and say that they "do" form hydrates.
What you should consider is that the equilibrium towards such hydrates is extremely unfavorable, making them **virtually non-existent**.

There have been, anyway, clever ways of "blocking" those forms as orthoesters. If I recall correctly, Corey used a protecting group of the OBO family in the synthesis of a natural product.

A more recent paper, which describes a protecting group of that nature, is this:
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ol047493n?journalCode=orlef7

Anyway, in normal mechanism-writing, that hydrate is not considered, being highly unfavored and unlikely to form.

Comment: Ortho esters are well known (i.e. trimethylorthoformate). Ortho acids are not known