# Why is triethyl orthoformate stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, stability, ethers

Geminal diols or triols are very unstable and are easily converted into keto or carboxylic compounds. Triethyl orthoformate is a triether of similar structure. I want to know why the former is so unstable and the latter stable.

Comment: Why are *gem*-diols unstable have you thought? Does the reason you have found imply that *gem*-diethers are unstable as well?

Comment: Initially i thought that they are unstable because of stearic hindrance but when I first came across triethyl orthoformate i realised that this is not the case.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with steric stuff. (You can have links to four C all right, and O is smaller than C.) Long story short, this is because H is labile and R is not.

Comment: Okay then what exactly is happening?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/what-makes-c-o-more-stable-that-coh%e2%82%82

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? This question asks for CH(OR)3 while the question in the link asks for CH(OH)3. I don't think this is a duplicate.