# Hydration in Chloral

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Chloral consists of two OH bonds on the same carbon, which is usually unstable, and leads to the evolution of a water molecule, and converts into an aldehyde. However, this is not observed in chloral, and there must be a reason for this.

I have come up with 2 possibilities:

1. hydrogen bonding in chloral, although it is quite weak
2. high EN of the chlorines, which results in a huge partial positive charge on C

Which reasoning, if any, is correct, and why does it dominate over the other?

Comment: Usually hydrogen bonding is used to explain the stability of chloral hydrate.

Comment: As mentioned by you, the effect of two chlorine atoms is dominant

Comment: See where chloral is discussed in [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/what-makes-c-o-more-stable-that-coh%e2%82%82/10739#10739) earlier answer.