# Acetal/ketal formation and deprotection

Tags: organic-chemistry

During acetal/ketal formation and deprotection, the same thing is used essentially which is acid and some sort of alcohol like ethylene glycol. And once deprotection occurs by the use of acid, ethylene glycol would be in solution so it would be essentially the starting material for the protection of a ketone or aldehyde. Is there some sort of external factors that favour acetal/ketal formation and others that favour deprotection or am I missing something here?

Comment: very similar to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/what-makes-c-o-more-stable-that-coh%e2%82%82

Comment: I don't think it is the same because my question is about protection and deprotection, not essential about the bond stability of the two products of ketone/aldehyde and acetal/ketal

Comment: acidic medium promotes "deprotection" and basic medium vice versa. This is because H+ in acidic medium makes one of the oxygen linkage a good leaving group enabling the other oxygen to remove it since the carbocation is stable.

Comment: But aren't they both done in acidic medium?

Comment: no only "deprotection" is done in acidic medium. acetals are pretty unstable in acidic medium.

Comment: Wait then why do most mechanisms involve H3O+ in acetal formation.

Comment: The protection is done in anhydrous acidic media often with removal of water (D-S reflux). The deprotection is done in aqueous so that the molecules of alcohol/glycol that are removed are vastly outnumbered by the water present and there is very little chance of the acetal reforming.